# Nested loop vectorisation

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I'm trying to vectorise a nested loop with a condition. below is a small dummy program of what i'm trying to do. the full version of the code would be pushing the memory limits of my pc (more nested loops and more complicated conditional) so i'm looking to also use broadcasting to keep memory usage to a minimum - ie just holding the final results no just a big file with some elements marked for exclusion.

i guess i need 'where' or a mask but the problem is the code is not iterating over both arrays. any help would be greatly appreciated. :-)

```py
#conventional python
import numpy as np
myList = []
count = 0
for a in range(5):
  for b in range(5):
    if a != b:
      myList.append([a, b])
    else:
      count += 1

print(myList)

#attempt at vectorised numpy
a = np.arange(5).reshape(1,5)
b = np.arange(5)
output = np.where(a != b, [a,b])
print(output)
```

Comment: `np.argwhere(a.T!=b)`?

Comment: The problem you state is with the memory usage, typically vectorisation will not help allot with that.

Comment: thanks, that works great :-)

Comment: `np.vstack((1-np.eye(5)).nonzero()).T` Will also give the same list, and it is easier to cluster. Or better yet `np.vstack((~np.eye(5, dtype=bool)).nonzero()).T`